# how to sum every row within date range in variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

df1:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
ex1 <- tibble(date = seq.Date(from = ymd('20200101'), length.out = 100, by = 'day'),
          a = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 2),
          b = runif(100, min = 1, max = 2),
          c = rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1),
          d = runif(100, min = 50, max = 60))
```

df2:

```
cal_c <- tibble(variable = c('a', 'b', 'c','d'),
                    start = c(ymd('20200101', '20200103', '20200203', '20200103')),
                    end = c(ymd('20200204', '20200405', '20200301', '20200401')),
                    total = c('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'))
```

I want to calc every row in df2 within the date range in the start and end based on df1, say a$toal between '2020-1-1' to '2020-2-4', b$total between '2020-1-3' to '2020-4-5', any help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence of `start` and `end` dates for `cal_c` data, get `ex1` in long format and join. We can then `sum` `value` for each `variable`.

```
library(tidyverse)

cal_c %>%
  mutate(date = map2(start, end, seq, by = 'day')) %>%
  unnest(date) %>%
  left_join(ex1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = 'variable'),
                    by = c('variable', 'date')) %>%
   group_by(variable, start, end) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#  variable start      end         value
#  <chr>    <date>     <date>      <dbl>
#1 a        2020-01-01 2020-02-04   34.3
#2 b        2020-01-03 2020-04-05  136. 
#3 c        2020-02-03 2020-03-01   79.5
#4 d        2020-01-03 2020-04-01 4909.
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
cal_c$total <- sapply(split(cal_c, rownames(cal_c)), function(x){
  sum(ex1[((ex1$date  >= x$start) & (ex1$date <= x$end)), match(x$variable, names(ex1))])})
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`:

```
cal_c[, total :=
    ex1[cal_c, on=.(date>=start, date<=end), by=.EACHI,
        sum(.SD[[variable]])]$V1
    ]
```

output:

```
   variable      start        end      total
1:        a 2020-01-01 2020-02-04   34.04780
2:        b 2020-01-03 2020-04-05  135.40290
3:        c 2020-02-03 2020-03-01   91.10271
4:        d 2020-01-03 2020-04-01 4978.59884
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
library(data.table)
ex1 <- data.table(date = seq.Date(from = as.IDate('20200101', format="%Y%m%d"), length.out = 100, by = 'day'),
    a = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 2),
    b = runif(100, min = 1, max = 2),
    c = rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1),
    d = runif(100, min = 50, max = 60))

cal_c <- data.table(variable = c('a', 'b', 'c','d'),
    start = as.IDate(c('20200101', '20200103', '20200203', '20200103'), format="%Y%m%d"),
    end = as.IDate(c('20200204', '20200405', '20200301', '20200401'), format="%Y%m%d"))
```